# Node.js Array to text with newline

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, file, hex

I wanted to convert an array to a textfile with a newline separating each entry.

I found out about an npm package called array-to-txt-file.
Here is the webpage:
[array-to-txt-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-to-txt-file)

This package claims that will concatenate every element of the array with a newline, so that every element of the array appears on its own line on the text file.

So i gave it a try and while it works great it doesn't concatenate the elements with a newline. Where one element ends, another one begins.

So i took a look at the source code of the package and this is the code that creates this effect.

```
try {
    array.forEach(v => {
      if(_.isPlainObject(v)) {
        ws.write(`${JSON.stringify(v)}\n`)
        return
      }
      ws.write(`${v}\n`)
    })
```

Especially the `ws.write(`${v}\n`)` part.

I then imported my output text file into a hex editor. In the hex editor there was dot between each element. Now, this dot was different to a regular dot.

While a regular dot has the hex value of `2E`, the dot that appears between the elements has `0A`.
Please also note that i am using Windows 7, and when viewed with notepad, nothing appears between the elements - where one ends, another one begins straight up.

So is there a way to modify that line in the code i posted above, so it really creates a newline in that part?

Comment: Please add the output file here as code with your question or upload it somewhere on websites like pastebin.com and link it here.

Comment: Which text editor are you using to view the contents of the file?

Comment: Notepad.exe on Windows 7 doesn't handle new lines that only use `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `\r` (0D) is [CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) CHARACTER (U+000D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm)
- `\n` (OA) is [LINE FEED (LF) CHARACTER (U+000A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm)

On Linux, `\n` represents new line.

Two characters combined `\r\n` represent a new line on Windows.

Try replacing `\n` with `\r\n` in both the `write` statements inside `index.js` file of the module.

Those dots represent non-printable characters. While the regular dot `.` [FULL STOP (U+002E)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002e/index.htm) is represented by `2E`.

More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 9):

Is there some reason a simple `join` doesn't work for you?

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

console.log(arr); // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]

console.log(arr.join('\n'));
// a
// b
// c
// d
// e
// f

let text = arr.join('\n');

fs.writeFileSync('modified.txt', text, "utf8");
```

If you need to you can replace `\n` with `\r\n` in the join as @Saif suggests, but I don't seem to need to, perhaps vscode is doing this automatically for me though.  I'm on a Windows machine.